# When to use references versus types versus boxes and slices versus vectors as arguments and return types?

Tags: memory-management, types, rust

I've been working with Rust the past few days to build a new library (related to abstract algebra) and I'm struggling with some of the best practices of the language. For example, I implemented a longest common subsequence function taking `&[&T]` for the sequences. I figured this was Rust convention, as it avoided copying the data (`T`, which may not be easily copy-able, or may be big). When changing my algorithm to work with simpler `&[T]`'s, which I needed elsewhere in my code, I was forced to put the `Copy` type constraint in, since it needed to copy the `T`'s and not just copy a reference.

So my higher-level question is: what are the best-practices for passing data between threads and structures in long-running processes, such as a server that responds to queries requiring big data crunching? Any specificity at all would be extremely helpful as I've found very little. Do you generally want to pass parameters by reference? Do you generally want to avoid returning references as I read in the Rust book? Is it better to work with `&[&T]` or `&[T]` or `Vec<T>` or `Vec<&T>`, and why? Is it better to return a `Box<T>` or a `T`? I realize the word "better" here is considerably ill-defined, but hope you'll understand my meaning -- what pitfalls should I consider when defining functions and structures to avoid realizing my stupidity later and having to refactor everything?

Perhaps another way to put it is, what "algorithm" should my brain follow to determine where I should use references vs. boxes vs. plain types, as well as slices vs. arrays vs. vectors? I hesitate to start using references and `Box<T>` returns everywhere, as I think that'd get me a sort of "Java in Rust" effect, and that's not what I'm going for!

Comment: I am not very well-versed in algorithms for longest common subsequence, but it surprises me that you had to copy a `T`. You can take references to any particular element of the slice and take any sub-slice as you want, shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: @delnan It was this particular bit of code that did it, when I tried to push seq1[i] onto the return vector... any thoughts would be super helpful!!        let mut q = *backtrack_with_index(c,seq1,seq2,i-1,j-1);
      q.push((seq1[i], i));
      Box::new(q)

Comment: `&seq1[i]` will give you a reference. You will have to change the type of the vector, of course. Also, general advice: Don't use `Box<T>` when `T` works (and it works almost always except for trait objects and recursive types). It's just unnecessary clutter and indirection. For `T: Sized`, for purposes of ownership, borrow checking, moves, etc., `Box<T>` is exactly equivalent to `T`. I am 90% sure that you don't need a single Box anywhere in this algorithm.

Comment: Can you more clearly specify what you want to call your algorithm on, and more importantly what you want it to return?

Comment: @SebastianRedl The algorithm would be called on a large dataset, hence the preference to use pointers instead of moving around the actual (quite large) objects. Think of my goal as making a simple "service": a request is asynchronously received, processed by this algorithm, and then its response rendered to (say) JSON and pushed back over the wire. In this case, what are the best practices?